# html validation with multiple spaces in a form fails

Tags: javascript, html

I have a 'required' in a form. I then have a validation to check characters not allowed. This works except if multiple spaces are entered then it validates as ok.
I do this in the javascript validation:

```
var isGoodMatch = myform.match(/^[0-9\s(-)]*$/);
if (!isGoodMatch) {
   alert("The Emergency Contact number contains invalid characters." + myform);
   return false;
}
```

Comment: Another option would be to help the user out and remove the whitespace.  `myform.replace(' ', '');`

Comment: @Peter Brooks, can you clarify what is the pattern you are looking for ?

Comment: I am not looking for any pattern - just not allowing some characters. I want to prevent blanks ie space bar is counted as a value that is allowed,

Answer (score 0):

Look for things that are Not Good, trim the value, and verify Length:

```
var badMatchExpression = /[^0-9\s\(\)-]/,
    trimmed = myform.trim();

if(!trimmed.length || trimmed.match(badMatchExpression)){
    alert("The Emergency Contact number contains invalid characters." + myform);
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use HTML5 input validation pattern and / or `required` attribute on the form elements.

Before submitting (POST/PUT) to your server, run an additional js script check that the `input.value !== ''`.  Simething like:

```
var myInput = document.getElementById('my-input');
if(myInput.value !== ''){
  //Good to go now
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I could be misinterpreting the need, but I believe you need a capital S instead of lowercase s.

```
var num = '(425)-55 1-5555';
var regex = new RegExp(/^[0-9\S(-)]*$/);
var isGood = regex.test(num);
console.log(isGood);
```

Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/taylorackley/he5Loqu7/5/

Comment: I tried the uppercase "S" and it still allowed me to put in multiple spaces. I hit the space bar a couple of times (or more) in that field.

Comment: I tried the capital S with no success.
I had  tried trimming in javascript and comparing for a blank.
    var stripped = frm.contact.value;
    stripped = trim(stripped); 
The only thing that was never working was the ability to enter in multiple spaces.